# How to make GUI (python, c#, c++) for a 3D calculator model?

Tags: python, 3d, calculator, modeling

I was told, the best option is to use GUI environments like GTK or Qt, but don't know how to use these programms. How do I link a calculator code with a 3D model the easiest way? In Unity?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! This question invites conversation, and these are not the type of questions to be done in stack overflow. It is expected from the person posting a question to have already done extensive search, both on the web and on Stack Overflow specifically regarding their question, and try to narrow that to a question&answer type, not conversational

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a 3D calculator that works in Unity? I'm not sure exactly. I haven't used GTK or Qt, but you would basically take the code of a 2D calculator's buttons, and use it for the buttons on the 3D model.